# ExpressJS api testing throws Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, supertest

App will be started and works fine, so i can call my api:

```
"dev": "env-cmd ./.env nodemon ./src/index.js",
"test": "env-cmd ./test.env jest --watch"
```

*server.js:*

```
// Loading deps
const app = express();
...
// Loading middlewares, routes etc.
...
module.exports = app;
```

*index.js:*

```
const app = require('./server');

const port = process.env.API_PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`); // eslint-disable-line no-console
});
```

App runs as it should. When i will test the api via `supertest` i get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

[image]

*The app.test.js*

```
const request = require('supertest');
const { app } = require('../src/server');

test('Should render app information', (done) => {
    request(app)
    .get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/info')
    .expect(200, done);
});
```

The server is not running, when i will test. I learned that in some tutorials on the subject of api testing in express.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In your test file, there is an extra level of destructuring involved in the assignement to the app variable - which ends up not equal to the object returned by require('../src/server'), but instead to the app property value for this object, which is actually undefined.

Comment: But I have to bring the instance into the test file, right?!
Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, but do: const app = require('../src/server'); instead of: const { app } = require('../src/server');

Answer (score 0):

on  server.js: `const express=require('express')`  is there ? then initializing

```
const app = express();
```

Comment: Sure it is. 
I just did not want to list all dependencies.
As written above, the application runs without problems